# jQuery File Upload blueimp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery template upload blueimp file.
What condition must be added in the template to limit the number of additions to 6  ? 
Here is the template :

```js
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <ul class="photogroduit template-upload fade ">
        <ul class="infosgalleries">
            <li>
                <div class="boxgallerie ">
                    <span class="preview"></span>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                    <a class="boxcontenucancel" href=""><span>P</span></a>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

I tried this but it does not work:  :

```js
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
   if(i < 6) {
       break;
   }
```

Comment: Explain, in the body of the question, what "it does not work" means.

Comment: You need to change the limit of for.

Change to:

{% for (var i=0, file; 6; i++) { %}

Comment: Have you tried like this

`{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
   {% if(i < 6) { %}
       break;
   {% } %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only six iteration, then do it like this

```
{% var file; %}
{% for (var i=0; i < 6; i++) { %}
{%     file = o.files[i]; %}

// rest of the code
```

Comment: I used your code but it does not work.
You can see.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzYdgo

Comment: Try by initializing `file` before loop and do `file=o.files[i]` in the body of loop. so leaving the loop like this `{% for (var i=0; i < 6; i++) { %}`. It is much cleaner.

Comment: By the way it won't hurt to initialize `file` inside the loop body :) ... like this

`{% for (var i=0; i < 6; i++) { %}
{%     var file = o.files[i]; %}`

Comment: Yes that's what I want 6 iterations.
Perfectly you are right it is better to declare the file outside the loop.
But nothing works when I execute the code :'(    I don't see where is the mistake.  
You can see  : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyaXMe

Comment: According to the given information, this should work fine. Kindly reply to @jdv comment and give us more information.